# Why does JSON.parse fail to parse this JSON string: `{ "Search results: \":s\"": "" }`?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonlint

Why does `JSON.parse` fail to parse the JSON string below?

Is this not valid JSON?

Strangely, https://jsonlint.com/ validates this string even though its custom [JSON parser](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint/blob/master/lib/jsonlint.js) throws the same error as `JSON.parse`.

**JSON string**

```
{
    "Search results: \":s\"": ""
}
```

**Code**

```
let test = `{
    "Search results: \":s\"": ""
}`
JSON.parse(test);
```

**Result**

> VM1882:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position
> 22
> at JSON.parse ()
> at :1:6

Comment: The backslash characters quote the `"` characters for the outer-level string. You have to double the backslashes because there are two parsing phases.

Comment: or you have to `let test = String.raw\`{ ... }\``

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the fast response. to clarify, https://jsonlint.com/ is wrong to consider this JSON valid?

Comment: @Thomas using `String.raw` seems to work. do you know why? also would you like to post as an answer?

Comment: No, jsonlint.com is not wrong, this is valid JSON. The problem is you're typing it verbatim into a JavaScript document without escaping it for JavaScript. If you placed the identical contents into a text file, loaded the text file and then parsed the contents as JSON, it would work fine.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the response. this helped us find the actual problem. (this question was simplified.)

Comment: @meagar thanks for the clarification. this was a simplified problem, and these answers helped unmask the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

Use double backslashes to escape quotes in JavaScript strings that are meant to be be parsed as JSON:

```js
let test = `{
  "Search results: \\":s\\"": ""
}`
console.log(JSON.parse(test));
```

> `{ 'Search results: ":s"': '' }`

As noted in the comments above, the problem occurs when writing quotes in JavaScript code strings because the backslash itself has to be escaped to remain in the string as a backslash for JSON.parse in the future. JavaScript treats the first backslash in a string as an escape character, not as the literal character as necessary for this case. If the data is read from another source than JavaScript code, only a single backslash is necessary.

Comment: thanks. this helped us find the root cause. the question was a simplified version of the problem.